# Use of Ruby on Rails for Oracle data warehouses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, data-warehouse

Could someone give me a hand by pointing me to an example of the use of Ruby on Rails with an Oracle data warehouse that has attributes such as the following:

- As is the case with many Oracle systems, the objects are not simply in the form of data tables, but are true objects in the computer science sense.  In this case, the objects are defined with the help of PL/SQL packages and stored procedures.
- The Oracle system  makes use of such features as concatenated primary keys and Index Organized Tables ( IOTS ). [ In Index Organized Tables, there is no separate index; some or all of the columns define the index.]
- The Oracle system makes use of additional Oracle features for optimization such as data partitions, SQL*Result caches, and so on.
- The overall system architecture is balanced in the sense that some of the business logic can reside in the database in PL/SQL stored procedures.  But  there is no "dogmatic" or "purist" approach that is taken.  In the balanced approach, business logic of different kinds is not solely done using PL/SQL.  It can also reside in systems of rules or workflows done with the help of modern rules or workflow engines.  Finally, views of the data as well as business logic can also be done with the help of components written in Ruby or Ruby On Rails, in order to reap the benefits that these tools provide and that can complement the use of PL/SQL components innate to many ( or most ) Oracle systems of complex nature.

If the answer to some of the question is "No", is there someone that can help give us guidance so that we can add Ruby and Ruby On Rails capabilities to an Oracle database with those features.  I am happy to generate additional kinds of Ruby wrappers and other files in order to carry out that task.

Thanks

Comment: `If the answer to some of the question[s] is "No"` er.. which questions?

Comment: @Mladen: The questions are implied and are pretty much "can Rails work with a database that uses these Oracle features?".

Comment: Rails wants to control the whole database and treat it like a dumb data store, you'll probably end up fighting with Rails and ActiveRecord every step of the way.

Comment: @mu, I think I understood the point, but the question boils over with phrases as `in order to reap the benefits that these tools provide and that can complement the use of PL/SQL components innate to many ( or most ) Oracle systems of complex nature`, with little or no concrete problems named. AR is written to be as DB-agnostic as possible - everything turns into plain SQL. I guess one could write a specific driver for some specific Oracle feature (similar to different NoSQL drivers around, just the opposite)...

Comment: ... but the OP gives no details about which parts he needs covered the most. What did he try (or contemplate) and what actual problem did he encounter? For example, why would Rails care if the table is IOTS or not, and why he put that as a bullet? Other databases can also use partitioning, but that is something AR doesn't have to see at all. Etc.